# Usage of Postgres NOTIFY / LISTEN in SQLALCHEMY with asyncpg

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

I would like to implement a subsystem where inserts in a certain table in `Postgres` would triger event and this event would be intercepted by backend on `FastAPi` with `SQLAlchemy` and `Websockets` and would be propogated towards frontend.

I have created a trigger in `Postgres` which sends notifications on inserts:

```sql
     """
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION detentions_event()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ DECLARE record RECORD; payload JSON; 
    BEGIN
    
      IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
          THEN record = NEW;
          END IF;

      IF record = new  THEN
            payload = json_build_object('table', TG_TABLE_NAME, 'action', TG_OP, 'data', row_to_json(record));
            PERFORM pg_notify('detentions', payload::text);
            Raise Notice 'Created Detention notification';
        END IF;

      RETURN NULL;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;   

CREATE TRIGGER notify_detention_event AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON detentions FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE
    PROCEDURE detentions_event();
```

Here on StackOverflow i found an article about usage of `NOTIFY / LISTEN` but only for `Psycopg2`  -- [Waiting for a row update or row insertion with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285563/waiting-for-a-row-update-or-row-insertion-with-sqlalchemy).

I had installed Psycopg2 and did check workability of the aforementioned trigger - it does work correctly.

Problem is that - i use asyncpg driver for SQLAlchemy and it is not obvious how to implement listening of notifications from PG with `asyncpg`.

In documentaion on `asyncpg` i have found that there is a  fucntion `add_listener` https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.connection.Connection.add_listener   but how to use it to intercept notifications is not clear.

```py
c = await session.connection()
r = await c.get_raw_connection()
#  r.driver_connection  -- raw asyncpg connect

def callback(connection, pid, chanel, payload):
    print(payload)

await r.driver_connection.add_listener('detentions', callback)
```

This code above does not intercepts any notifications from `Postgres` but code with `pycopg2` from here  [Waiting for a row update or row insertion with sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285563/waiting-for-a-row-update-or-row-insertion-with-sqlalchemy) does.

I would be glad to hear if anyone has any idea / experience how to implement `NOTIFY / LISTEN` in `SQLAlchemy` with `asyncpg`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use SQLAlchemy event listeners instead? Or do you have to stick to PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Louis Huang . I guess i should not use events in this case as it is no guarantee that process that creates something in DB and triggers alchemy event would be the same process that serves websocket -> event might not be intercepted.

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem, considering using https://pypi.org/project/asyncpg-listen/ but have not gotten it to work yet